How to modify this VBA excel script to capture a user selected region?
I found this VBA script online that helps with converting image URLs into actual images in an excel sheet. I need to modify it so that it captures the cells selected by the user (Ie: an entire user-selected column) instead of the cells being hard-coded. I've tried using selection and I can't get it to work for some reason. When I run it using the selection method it does nothing. How can I go about making this work?
Sub URLPictureInsert()

    Dim Pshp As Shape
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCol As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A10") -> This works
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select) 'This does not work
    For Each cell In Rng
        filenam = cell
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filenam).Select
        Set Pshp = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
        Pshp.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        If Pshp Is Nothing Then GoTo lab
        xCol = cell.Column + 1
        Set xRg = Cells(cell.Row, xCol)
        With Pshp
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Width = 60
           .Height = 30
            .Top = xRg.Top + (xRg.Height - .Height) / 2
            .Left = xRg.Left + (xRg.Width - .Width) / 2
        End With
lab:
    Set Pshp = Nothing
    Range("A2").Select
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Pe4rhaps Set Rng = ActiveCell.EntireColumn

Set rng = Selection. Side note, you normally don't want to use a blanket On Error Resume Next.

Insert Pictures Next to a Column of Their Locations (Paths)

The web page of the original code is titled How to convert image URLs to actual images in Excel?

Sub InsertPicturesNextToColumnOfPaths()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Insert Pictures Next to Column of Paths"
    Const INSERT_PICTURE_COLUMN_OFFSET As Long = 1
    Const MAX_PICTURES As Long = 1000
    
    ' Validate the selection.
    
    ' Check if the selection is 'Nothing' (e.g. no visible workbook open).
    If Selection Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no selection (""Nothing"")!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Check if the selection is not a range (e.g. could be a shape).
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then
        MsgBox "The selection (""" & TypeName(Selection) & """) " _
           & "is not a range!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the source range (the selection) and its worksheet.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Selection
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = srg.Worksheet
    
    ' Retrieve the number of cells of the source range.
    Dim CellsCount As Double: CellsCount = srg.Cells.CountLarge
    ' The Long data type doesn't cover all worksheet cells (since Excel 2007).
    
    ' Check if the number of cells exceeds the specified max number.
    If CellsCount > MAX_PICTURES Then
        MsgBox "The procedure is set up to retrieve a maximum of " _
            & MAX_PICTURES & " pictures at a time!" & vbLf & vbLf _
            & CellsCount & " cells are selected!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Check if all cells of the selection are not in a single column.
    If CellsCount <> Intersect(srg, ws.Columns(srg.Column)) _
            .Cells.CountLarge Then
        MsgBox "The selection must be in a single column!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Insert pictures.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim scell As Range, dcell As Range, shp As Shape
    Dim ErrNumber As Long, PicturesCount As Long, PicturePath As String
    Dim WasPictureInserted As Boolean
    
    For Each scell In srg.Cells
        ' Insert.
        PicturePath = CStr(scell.Value)
        WasPictureInserted = False
        On Error Resume Next
            ws.Pictures.Insert PicturePath
            WasPictureInserted = (Err.Number = 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        ' Reference and format.
        If WasPictureInserted Then
            Set shp = ws.Shapes(ws.Shapes.Count)
            Set dcell = scell.Offset(, INSERT_PICTURE_COLUMN_OFFSET)
            With shp
                .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                If .Width > dcell.Width Then .Width = dcell.Width * 2 / 3
                If .Height > dcell.Height Then .Height = dcell.Height * 2 / 3
                .Top = dcell.Top + (dcell.Height - .Height) / 2
                .Left = dcell.Left + (dcell.Width - .Width) / 2
            End With
            PicturesCount = PicturesCount + 1
        End If
    Next scell
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     
    ' Select the top-most cell of the source range.
    'Application.Goto srg.Cells(1)
     
    ' Inform.
     
    MsgBox PicturesCount & " picture" & IIf(PicturesCount = 1, "", "s") _
        & " inserted.", IIf(PicturesCount = 0, vbExclamation, vbInformation), _
        PROC_TITLE
     
End Sub

